# How to assign a logged in user automatically to a post In Django Rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have created a model to post an ad. Since the CreateApiView is protected so that only logged in user can create or post ad, but if the logged in user posts an ad how to automatically take the logged user name or assign that user to his ad?

This is what I have tried in my viewsets

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

this is my models.py

```
class Add(models.Model):
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Khashi'),
    (2, 'Boka'),
    (3, 'Goat'),
    (4, 'Chyangra'),
    (5, 'Veda'),
)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(("Title"), max_length=50)
category = models.IntegerField(("Choose Category"), choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
Short_discription = models.CharField(("Short Discription"), max_length=200)
```

this is my serializers.py

```
class KhashiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Add
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['user']
```

this is my viewset

```
class KhashiCreateApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Add.objects.all()
    serializer_class = KhashiSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

I'm getting this error with this endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/khashi/khashi_add

```
OperationalError at /api/khashi/khashi_add
table add_khashi_add has no column named user_id
```

Is there any way to assign user to the post so that if POST reqest in Postman without `user` provided will automatically assign logged in user or user with Token that is provided in Authorization header??

Comment: `read_only_fields = ['user']`?

Comment: I removed that from my code also.... But didn't work

Comment: Add some more info like how you're calling this endpoint. And ensure `perform_create` is being called. `pdb` is your friend.

Comment: @dan-klasson question updated ;)

Comment: Run `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: @dan-klasson Didn't work :(

Comment: What's the name of your model then?

Comment: It's Add... question updated

Comment: I would try dropping and re-creating the db. Not sure why makemigrations isn't working for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I figure it out by myself....
I just update my serializers.py using validate method

```
class KhashiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Add
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ['user']

def validate(self, attrs):
    attrs['user'] = self.context['request'].user
    return attrs
```

Comment: overriding `create` method of serializer is more preferred to add user in object from serializer context instead of `validate` method, its purpose is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

You had it in your original post: overriding `perform_create` in the viewset worked for me in automatically adding the logged in user to the object:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

It looks like you're running into a separate issue with the user_id column not existing on your table.